# CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE

Tags: css, firefox, font-face, file-uri

The following code works in Google Chrome beta as well as IE 7. However, Firefox seems to have a problem with this. I'm suspecting it to be a problem of how my CSS files are included, cause I know Firefox is not too friendly about cross-domain imports.

But this is all just static HTML and there's no question of cross-domain.

On my landing-page.html I do a CSS import like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
```

Within the main.css I have another imports like so:

```
@import url("reset.css");
@import url("style.css");
@import url("type.css");
```

and within the type.css I have the following declarations:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "DroidSerif Regular";
        src: url("font/droidserif-regular-webfont.eot");
        src: local("DroidSerif Regular"), 
                url("font/droidserif-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"), 
                url("font/droidserif-regular-webfont.ttf")     format("truetype"), 
                url("font/droidserif-regular-webfont.svg#webfontpB9xBi8Q")     format("svg"); 
    font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
@font-face {
    font-family: "DroidSerif Bold";
    src: url("font/droidserif-bold-webfont.eot");
    src: local("DroidSerif Bold"), 
        url("font/droidserif-bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), 
        url("font/droidserif-bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), 
        url("font/droidserif-bold-webfont.svg#webfontpB9xBi8Q") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }

body { font-family: "DroidSerif Regular", serif; }
h1 { font-weight: bold; font-family: "DroidSerif Bold", serif; }
```

I have a directory called "font" in the same location as type.css. This font directory contains all the woff/ttf/svg files etc.

I'm stumped on this one. **It works in Chrome and IE but not on Firefox**. How is this possible? What am I missing?

Comment: I'm running into this exact problem with FontSquirrel generated directives and fonts at this moment.

Comment: for testing purposes can you try adding the @font-face declarations to your html between `<style>` tags and see if you have the same problem?

Comment: adding a single comma may solve this issue too, like: url('Sans-serif') format('woff')

Answer (score 239, accepted):

#### LOCALLY RUNNING THE SITE (`file:///`)

Firefox comes with a very strict "file uri origin" (`file:///`) policy by default: to have it to behave just as other browsers, go to `about:config`, filter by `fileuri` and toggle the following preference:

`security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`

Set it to **false** and you should be able to load local font resources across different path levels.

#### PUBLISHED SITE

As per my comment below, and you are experiencing this problem after deploying your site, you could try to add an additional header to see if your problem configures itself as a cross domain issue: it shouldn't, since you are specifying relative paths, but i would give it a try anyway: in your .htaccess file, specify you want to send an additional header for each .ttf/.otf/.eot file being requested:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Frankly, I wouldn't expect it to make any difference, but it's so simple it's worth trying: else try to use *base64 encoding* for your font typeface, ugly but it may works too.

A nice recap is available [here](http://geoff.evason.name/2010/05/03/cross-domain-workaround-for-font-face-and-firefox/)

Comment: If you are not working locally, then this will probably not solve that, but you may want to use root-based paths on a live site anyway, that is, "/resources/font" instead of relative ones such as "../font", but i don't know about thumblr: if you can give out the url for the site i can give it a look.

Comment: The font declaration works fine in Chrome, Safari, even all they way back to IE6... but not firefox.

Comment: Ah you are speaking about the infamous cross-domain problem: you can either use your font in a base64 encoding, or ask thumblr to add an additional "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header when serving fonts.

Comment: Then how ridiculously strict is Firefox's cross domain policy? Like, the CDN and the site share the same domain, just different subdomains.

Comment: @jason: When I load your page in Firefox 3.6.9, it loads the Gotham Round font just fine. Are you still having the problem?

Comment: I cant' see the font being rendered correctly in Firefox, but there are no problems in Chrome (i'm using Ubuntu btw).

Comment: @rossisdead Yes, FF 3.6.9 on Windows, no dice.

Comment: @jason, the messy 64 bit encoding doesn't work either? It worked for me.

Comment: Many thanks! Strangely, without this fix the font worked fine in FF20 on Mountain Lion, but not in FF20 on Snow Leopard. Grrr!

Comment: Works for me! (btw @scottyd, I was having the problem in SL) Oddly I had this problem *only* on the first page visited on my domain. E.g. load x.com, and everything was Times. Click a link to x.com/page2 and the webfonts loaded. Click a link back to x.com and the default page now loads with the webfonts. I didn't test whether this was specific to the domain's default page, or if it would have happened starting a new window at x.com/page2 too… and now I can't, because even when I revert to a pristine htaccess FF loads the webfonts (even with a hard reload, and exiting FF) - it learned?!

Comment: To those devs that are needing to do this but use Amazon's S3 service and cannot directly control the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header via S3 properties, you need to add a CORS policy to your bucket to explicitly allow your domain in.  FF works like a champ after that.  If your S3 bucket is the origin for a Cloudfront dist, you must invalidate cached files to force Cloudfront to re-cache the object WITH the new (CORS) headers.

Answer (score 42):

In addition to adding the following to your .htaccess: (thanks @Manuel)

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

You may want to try explicitly adding the webfont mime types to the .htaccess file... like this:

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff
```

In the end, my .htaccess file looks like this (for the section that enables webfonts to work in all browsers)

```
# BEGIN REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS

AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# END REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS
```

Comment: Did the trick for me as well. I had to add woff2 as well:
AddType font/woff2 .woff2

Answer (score 16):

I've had this problem too. I found the answer here: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=63628

This is an example of the solution that works on firefox, you need to add this line to your font face css:

```
src: local(font name), url("font_name.ttf");
```

Comment: Putting a `local('name')` in the `font-face` declaration just means "try to load font 'name' on the user's computer. if it isn't found, load the webfont." (see [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)). Still, glad it worked for you! :)

Comment: It worked "For you" because you had the font installed on your computer. Other users wont see it. You fixed it just for you.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem.  Double check your code for H1, H2 or whatever style you are targeting with the @font-face rule. I found I was missing a coma after `font-family: 'custom-font-family' Arial, Helvetica etc` It was showing up fine in every browser apart from Firefox. I added the coma and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I'll just leave this here because my co-worker found a solution for a related "font-face not working on firefox but everywhere else" problem.

The problem was just Firefox messing up with the font-family declaration, this ended up fixing it:

```
body{ font-family:"MyFont" !important; }
```

PS: I was also using html5boilerplate.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem. I had to create a new folder called "fonts" and put it in wp_content. I can access it from my browser like this ***http://www.example.com/wp-content/fonts/CANDY.otf***

Previously, the fonts folder was in the same directory as my CSS file, and the @font-face looked like this:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: CANDY;
    src: url("fonts/CANDY.otf");
}
```

As i mentioned above, this was not working in Firefox but only with Chrome. Now it is working because I used an absolute path:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: CANDY;
    src: url("http://www.example.com/wp-content/fonts/CANDY.otf");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly this problem running ff4 on a mac. I had a local development server running and my @font-face declaration worked fine. I migrated to live and FF would 'flash' the correct type on first page load, but when navigating deeper the typeface defaulted to the browser stylesheet.

I found the solution lay in adding the following declaration to .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

found [via](http://doctype.com/anyone-clue-me-my-fontface-declaration-working-firefox-alternate-domain-name)

Answer (score 3):

One easy solution that no one's mentioned yet is embedding the font directly into the css file using base64 encoding.

If you're using fontsquirrel.com, in the font-face Kit Generator choose **expert mode**, scroll down and select **Base64 Encode** under **CSS Options** - the downloaded Font-Kit will be ready to plug and play.

This also has the fringe benefit of reducing page load time because it requires one less http request.

Comment: the comments on the picked solution do mention the base64 encode solution.

Comment: @KaushikGopal I think the answer must have been edited after I posted this.

Answer (score 3):

I'd mention that some fonts have issues in firefox if their filename contains specific characters. I've recently run into an issue with the font 'Modulus' which had a filename '237D7B_0_0'. Removing the underscores in the filename and updating the css to match the new filename solved this problem. Other fonts with similar characters don't have this issue which is very curious...probably a bug in firefox. I'd recommend keeping filenames just to alphanumeric characters.

Comment: THIS. MyFonts.com spits out their font files named this way and it results in Firefox 35 rendering in all sorts of bizarre ways. Renaming the font solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For this font in particular you should be using the Google Font API:

http://code.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Droid+Sans

If you still want to use FontSquirrel's kit generator, use the Smiley hack option to eliminate local font problems. After you've generated a kit, check that the generated demo.html works in FireFox. I bet it does. Now upload it to your server -- I bet it works there too since FontSquirrel is awesome.

However, if you broke the generated kit code while integrating it into your project, use the standard methods of debugging -- check for 404's and go line by line until you find the problem. WOFF should definitely work in FF, so thats a good place to start.

Finally, if none of this works, update FireFox. I wrote all this assuming that you are using the latest; but you didn't specify what version you are checking in, so that could be your problem too.

Comment: Actually you shouldn't use the Google Font API for this. There's a problem with Firefox which prevents the font variants (italic, bold, etc) to be used if you have the font installed locally. Only way around this I've found is to nerf the local src declaration with the smiley (of course, any weird character(s) would do, it's just so... happy).

Comment: Here's a link to the bug report: http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=13

Answer (score 2):

Try nerfing the local source declaration in your `@font-face` directives.

There's a known bug in either Firefox or the Google Font API that prevents the variants of fonts to be used if the font is installed locally, and matches the defined local name:

http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=13

To effectively nerf the local declaration, just make your local source string some nonsense. The generally accepted convention for this is to use a the smiley unicode character (`"☺"`). Why? Paul Irish has a great explanation up on his blog:

http://paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/#smiley

Comment: Didn't know PaulI came up with a new bullet method, will have to try this one and see if it solves my FF font-face issues.

Comment: [Update: While helpful, it doesn't solve the issue].I did get pointed though to the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing this in local files or off a Web server?  Files in different directories are considered different domains for cross-domain rules, so if you're testing locally you could be hitting cross-domain restrictions.

Otherwise, it would probably help to be pointed to a URL where the problem occurs.

Also, I'd suggest looking at the Firefox error console to see if any CSS syntax errors or other errors are reported.

Also, I'd note you probably want font-weight:bold in the second @font-face rule.

Comment: Hmm.. yes David, i do seem to be running it locally, but i previously had it has a subdirectory withing the same directory. So my type.css lies in the root folder and within the same place lies the font folder. so type.css and the font folder are in the same directory. 
To be on the safe side, i also tried removing it from the directory and directly placing the fonts. It still doesn't work on firefox.

Comment: I'm now beginning to feel it's one of the two:
1) something wrong in my coding, if anyone spots anything from above code, please be so kind as to point it out.
2) FF doesn't treat @font-face and multiple file imports nicely? I use main.css which inturn imports @import type.css which in turn has the folder link to the fonts?
Any light folks? 

Btw thanks for the font-weight catch @David!

Comment: Firefox handles multiple imports just fine. What version are you using? Debug the code using FireBug; use process of elimination. Working locally introduces problems that might be eliminated remotely. This is how you debug!

Comment: "Files in different directories are considered different domains for cross-domain rules" - no, they're not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with how you setup your font-face's paths. Since you didn't start the path with a "/", Firefox will attempt to find the font's based on the path the stylesheet's in. So basically, Firefox is looking for your font in the "root/css/font" directory instead of the "root/font" directory. You can easily fix this by either moving the font folder to the css folder, or adding a / to the beginning of your font paths.

Try this out:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "DroidSerif Regular";
    src: url("/font/droidserif-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: local("DroidSerif Regular"), url("/font/droidserif-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/font/droidserif-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/font/droidserif-regular-webfont.svg#webfontpB9xBi8Q") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "DroidSerif Bold";
    src: url("/font/droidserif-bold-webfont.eot");
    src: local("DroidSerif Bold"), url("/font/droidserif-bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/font/droidserif-bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/font/droidserif-bold-webfont.svg#webfontpB9xBi8Q") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


body {
    font-family: "DroidSerif Regular" , serif;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "DroidSerif Bold";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an .htaccess Access Control Allow Origin rule didn't work for me when I was confronted with this issue.

Instead, in IIS in the web.config insert the system.webServer block shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This worked like a charm for me. If you need to restrict access to particular domain, replace the * with the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem getting a font to display properly in Firefox. Here is what I found to work for me. Add a slash before the directory holding the font in the url attribute. Here is my before and after versions:

```
B E F O R E:
   @font-face
{   font-family: "GrilledCheese BTN";
    src: url(fonts/grilcb__.ttf);
}

A F T E R:
@font-face
{   font-family: "GrilledCheese BTN";
    src: url(/fonts/grilcb__.ttf);
}
```

notice the leading slash before 'fonts' in the url? This tells the browser to start at the root directory and then access the resource. At least for me - Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to import external fonts you face one of the most common problem with your Firefox and other browser. Some time your font working well in google Chrome or one of the other browser but not in every browser.

There have lots of reason for this type of error one of the biggest reason behind this problem is previous per-defined  font. You need to add !important keyword after end of your each line of CSS code as below:

Example:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family:"Hacen Saudi Arabia" !important;
    src:url("../font/Hacen_Saudi_Arabia.eot?") format("eot") !important;
    src:url("../font/Hacen_Saudi_Arabia.woff") format("woff") !important;
    src: url("../font/Hacen_Saudi_Arabia.ttf") format("truetype") !important;
    src:url("../font/Hacen_Saudi_Arabia.svg#HacenSaudiArabia") format("svg") !important;
}
.sample
{
    font-family:"Hacen Saudi Arabia" !important;
}
```

Description:
Enter above code in your CSS file or code here. In above example replace "Hacen Saudi Arabia" with your font-family and replace url as per your font directory.

If you enter !important in your css code browser automatically focus on this section and override previously used property.
For More details visit: https://answerdone.blogspot.com/2017/06/font-face-not-working-solution.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more to add to the list. I discovered that if you specify a local `src` with a name that matches a generic font name, it breaks the entire rule in Firefox (and only Firefox). Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: code;
  src: local(Monaco),
       url(monaco.woff2) format("woff2"),
       local(monospace);
}
```

This will fail in Firefox (as of version 95.0.2) and display the text in the unstyled default (Times) because the last `src` value matches the name of a generic font (`monospace`) that's supported by Firefox. The following values all fail in the same way:

- `cursive`
- `fantasy`
- `monospace`
- `sans-serif`
- `serif`
- `system-ui`

It's an edge case for sure (and probably a bug), but it may help someone. You can't fall back to generic fonts this way, and if, for some reason, you really need to reference a local font of the same name, you should put it between quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with firebug if do you get some 404? I had problems in the pass and I found that the extension was the same but linux file.ttf is different from file.TTF... and it worked with all browsers except firefox.

Wish it helps!

Comment: I strongly doubt it would be 404'ing in only one browser and not others.

Comment: @jason One browser can use a filetype different from another. :)

Comment: Well, in the cases that I've ran into this issue, I can 100% say that Firebug's net panel shows it loading the font successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

http://geoff.evason.name/2010/05/03/cross-domain-workaround-for-font-face-and-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The fontsquirel demo page was working in FF but not my own page even though all files were coming from the same domain!

It turned out that I was linking my stylesheet with an absolute URL (http://example.com/style.css) so FF thought it was coming from a different domain. Changing my stylesheet link href to /style.css instead fixed things for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is a naming-issue, specifically with regard the use (or not) of spaces and hyphens.

I was having similair issue, which i thought i had fixed by placing *the optional* quotes (') around font-/family-names, but that actually implicitly fixed a naming issue.

I'm not completely up-to-date on the CSS-specification, and there is (at leat to me) some ambiguity in how different clients interpret the specs. Additionally, it also seems related to PostScript naming conventions, but please correct me if i'm wrong!

Anyway as i understand it now, your declaration is using a mixture of two possible distinct flavors.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "DroidSerif Regular";
```

If you'd consider ***Droid*** the actual family-name, of which **Sans** and **Serif** are members, just like for instance their children **Sans Regular** or **Serif Bold**, then you either use spaces everyhere to concatinate identifiers, OR you remove spaces and use CamelCasing for the familyName, and hyphens for sub-identifiers.

Applied to your declaration, it would look something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Droid Serif Regular";
```

OR

```
@font-face {
  font-family: DroidSerif-Regular;
```

I think both should be perfectly legal, either with or without the quotes, but i've had mixed success with that between various clients. Maybe, one day, i have some time to figure-out the details on this/these isseu/s.

I found this article helpful in understanding some of the aspects involved:
http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-font-family

This article has some more details on PostScript specifically, and some links to an Adobe specification PDF:
http://rachaelmoore.name/posts/design/css/find-font-name-css-family-stack/

Answer (score 0):

No need to mess around with settings just remove the quotes and spaces from the font-family:

this

```
body {font-family: "DroidSerif Regular", serif; }
```

becomes this

```
body {font-family: DroidSerifRegular, serif; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I sloved problem with inserting font-face style code

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face { 
font-family: 'Amazone';font-style: normal; 
/*font-weight:100; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-smooth:always;*/ 
src: local('Amazone'), url(font/Amazone.woff) format('woff');} 
</style>
```

direclty in header on your index.html or php page, in style tag.
Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Because of that this is one of the top Google results for this problem I would like to add what solved this problem for me:

I had to remove the format(opentype) from the src of the font-face, then it worked in Firefox as well. It worked fine in Chrome and Safari before that.

Answer (score 0):

May be its not because of your code, Its because of your Firefox configuration.

Try this from `Tool bar` **Western** to **Unicode**

```
View > Text Encoding > Unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding meta for content:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

This happens in Firefox and Edge if you have Unicode texts in your html.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox lets you switch off web fonts entirely. This was the case or me.

To turn it on, go to Preferences>Content>Advanced and check the box.

[related artice at fontspring](https://www.fontspring.com/support/font-face-bugs)

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how you created the syntax as I neved used svg in font declaration, but Font Squirel has a really good tool to create a bullet proof syntax font-face from just one font.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: Thanks rnaud, I infact used fontsquirrel for the above :) . Just reformatted with tabs and spaces to a readable form.

Comment: You've never used SVG in font declaration but you use Font Squirrel? Then you have used SVG in font declaration.

Comment: @jason: You can opt out of using SVG with Font Squirrel.

Answer (score -2):

Could also be the use of the URL in the path of the font-face tag. If you use "http://domain.com" it doesn't work in Firefox, for me changing it to "http://www.domain.com" worked.

Answer (score -2):

My problem was that Windows named the font 'font.TTF' and firefox expected 'font.ttf' i saw that after opening my project in linux, renamed the font to propper name and everything works