# @font-face font stacks suddenly died in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

The following CSS has been working for a good week or so, I have skipped back through the GIT repo to see where it breaks and it seems to be broken in all of the commits (leading me to believe I haven't done anything wrong).

Still works in Chrome.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Blackout2AM';
    src: url('../fonts/Blackout-fontfacekit/Blackout-2am-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Blackout-fontfacekit/Blackout-2am-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('../fonts/Blackout-fontfacekit/Blackout-2am-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Blackout-fontfacekit/Blackout-2am-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Blackout-fontfacekit/Blackout-2am-webfont.svg#webfontXyt5a0LX') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

.sidebar h2, .sidebar h3 a, #footer .menu a, .switcher li a, .dateLinks a{
    font-family: 'Blackout2AM';

}
```

Comment: Do the fonts exist? What does Firebug say about what it's loading?

Comment: Is it Firefox 4? If so, you might want to drop back to 3.6.16 and see how that goes.

Comment: The font files seem to be present in the CSS, in firebug. How can I tell if it is actually fetching the files?

Comment: I've been on Firefox 4 for weeks, no issue!!

Comment: just loaded in 3.6.16, same problem.

Comment: Duplicate of [css @font-face not working with firefox, but working with chrome and IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in `.htaccess`

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the font you are using and can (sort of) reproduce the problem.

If you define the `@font-face` twice, one with broken URLs and one with correct URLs, Firefox4 and Safari5 do not show the font at all but Chrome12 and Firefox3 are fine.

The order of the *correct* verses *broken* `@font-face` rules is also important as Firefox4 and Opera11 will only display the font if the *correct* rule is the last one. Safari5 will not display the font at all if there is a broken URL, regardless of the order.

**Edit:** Ah, if it's broken in Firefox 3 also, it might be [Firefox Bug 567573](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=567573)

Comment: an .htaccess hack from another question fixed it -> see comments.

Comment: Oh **that** problem! Was an interesting investigation for me nonetheless, if only to highlight that browsers are handling the invalid URLs very differently.