# Firefox not respecting @font-face?

Tags: firefox, cross-domain, cross-browser, font-face

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css @font-face not working with firefox, but working with chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

For some reason firefox (3.6 and 4) is not displaying a particular font on just one page, at http://tustincommercial.tumblr.com/

If you look in the css, you will see that the font-family is given as 'MuseoSans'. All other browsers show the correct font. Using firebug, firefox is computing the style correctly for the elements that should be museo, but it just isn't showing the font.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that Firefox in particular won't load font files for one site which are hosted in another domain, unless the server serving the fonts returns the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header as part of its http response, and the value in the header matches the domain of the site.

In my case the solution was to drop the following line into the .htaccess file for the directory hosting my fonts:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://tustincommercial.tumblr.com"
```

That enables access to my fonts for my tumblr blog, but not for other sites.