# Firefox 3.5 not showing webfonts

Tags: firefox, css, font-face, webfonts

I have some @font-face webfonts on my site. The fonts and the CSS code is generated via the [Font Squirrel @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). None of the fonts I embedded are showing in FF 3.5. FF 4 is working without a problem. The fonts are served from the same domain as the calling website. ATM I'm calling the website on a local network via local area IP.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArvoBold';
    src: url('font/arvo-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/arvo-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/arvo-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/arvo-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/arvo-bold-webfont.svg#ArvoRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Which version of FF? Might want to take a look at the browser compatibility for @font-face https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: [CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie/3704578#3704578)

You could try to add an additional header to see if your problem configures itself as a cross domain issue: it shouldn't, since you are specifying relative paths, but i would give it a try anyway: in your .htaccess file, specify you want to send an additional header for each .ttf/.otf/.eot file being requested:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>`
```

Also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-font-face-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: Just noticed that I forgot to delete my old @font-face declaration which caused the problem. Still accepting your answer, because I think it is the most useful for other users who may finde this question.