# Font-face not working in MAc

Tags: macos, font-face

I created font-face using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator. I have created  myriad pro semi bold and italic fonts using it for the website. The fonts are coming fine in PC machine but on the Mac the links are not looking as Myriad pro semibold.

Here is the link to the site where you can see.

http://www.vr2020.com/gtgtoursdev/index.php

font-face code :

```
@font-face {
font-family: "MyriadProSemibold";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),  url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semibold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semibold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semibold-webfont.svg#MyriadProSemibold") format("svg");
}
@font-face {
font-family: "MyriadProSemiboldCondensed";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semiboldcond-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semiboldcond-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semiboldcond-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semiboldcond-webfont.svg#MyriadProSemiboldCondensed") format("svg");
}
@font-face {
font-family: "MyriadProSemiboldItalic";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semiboldit-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semiboldit-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semiboldit-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("myriadpro/myriadpro-semiboldit-webfont.svg#MyriadProSemiboldItalic") format("svg");
}
@font-face {
font-family: "MyriadStdTilt";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url("myriadpro/myriadstd-tilt-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("myriadpro/myriadstd-tilt-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("myriadpro/myriadstd-tilt-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("myriadpro/myriadstd-tilt-webfont.svg#MyriadStdTilt") format("svg");
}
```

Thanks & Regards,
Karunakar Gowni

Comment: your question is not really clear... which browser / version ? which OSX version ?

Answer (score 0):

This post: [CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie) may help. I know it relates to Firefox, but you may find the solution there.

**Update:** Also, you're calling the stylesheet with your `@font-face` property in it after you call the stylesheet which you're using it in(voucher2.css). From what I saw you don't call any Myriad font in "menustyle.css".

Comment: Hi Andrew,I am not using Myriad font in menus thats the reason i have not used it in menustyle.css file. Its only being used in the popup that comes for offers.