# @font-face doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

I have a little problem and can't seem to figure out what the solution is.

I'm using `Museo` as a webfont. In `Safari` everything works like a charm, but in `Firefox` it doesn't work. 
Does anyone have any clue why?

```
@font-face {font-family: 'MuseoSans-500';
src: url('webfonts/eot/style_159303.eot');
src: url('webfonts/eot/style_159303.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('webfonts/woff/style_159303.woff') format('woff'),
url('webfonts/ttf/style_159303.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('webfonts/svg/style_159303.svg#MuseoSans-500') format('svg');}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you already have a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie

Comment: Hard to say anything useful without seeing your actual page.  Is your CSS in an `@media` rule?  Is the font file subtly broken so the OpenType sanitizer in Firefox rejects it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with your @font-face setup, but I've gotten Museo working in FireFox using @font-face. I'd recommend generating the CSS declarations and different font files using [Font Squirrel's @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) which automatically sets everything up for all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get it working and the font doesn't have to be *exactly* the same, maybe you should have a look at the [Google font API](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/getting_started.html). Just choose a font from the [list](http://code.google.com/webfonts) ('Ovo' or 'Forum' look quite similar to yours), import it in your website with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      type="text/css" 
      href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Font+Name">
```

...and then use it as a regular font in your CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Font Name', Verdana;
}
```

The best about it, besides that it's that easy: It even works with IE6.