# Firefox failing at fonts

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, fonts, rendering

I know this is a common issue, but I haven't been able to solve this issue. I'm using Pictos webfont via tumblr as a CDN on this blog http://mrelliotb.tumblr.com/, however, in FF it does not render. I'm looking for a way to make it work **and/or** a way to detect the failure in rendering as to remove the extraneous letters that should be rendered.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Check the comments on the accepted answer in this thread. It deals specifically with your problem:

[CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

In a nutshell, Firefox does not like the cross-domain hosting for the fonts, and you should base64 encode them directly in to the stylesheet

You can easily base64 encode your font by using this wizard and selecting advanced/Base64 encode.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 0):

from my browser, your font now is helvetics and not pictos web font. did you have some @font-face at your stylesheet? and second, if it is problem with firefox you just have to make sure your config at

**option->content-> advance button at font -> make sure your the setting is allow the web render its own font**

may this help