# Font does not load in firefox but works in chrome

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Having an issue with Font not sure why is loading for Chrome, but in Firefox it seems like it is not loaded.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LNC7h/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: it may be helpful for you http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems

Comment: fiddle works fine in Chrome, it means code is fine

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie

Answer (score 4):

Check out this SO thread, which had the exact same problem as you have. The suggested work around was offered in other communities and helped solving this issue:

- [css @font-face not working with firefox, but working with chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

Answer (score 2):

I think Firefox supports only `TrueType/OpenType TT(.ttf)` and `OpenType PS (.otf)`.

Have look at [this table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface).

**EDIT:** Your answer you find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie) i think.

Answer (score 2):

save font in same directory and apply like this this will work i have check in my firefox 12.0

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Play';
    src: url('play.ttf');
}
.font
{
    font-family: "play";
    font-size: 20px;
}

<p class="font">TESTING</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox will only accept relative path to fonts. If you want to use a different domain to host the font than the one where the page is located, you have to follow Mozilla's [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) policy:

> This cross-origin sharing standard is used to enable cross-site HTTP requests for:
>
> [...]
>
> Web Fonts (for cross-domain font usage in @font-face within CSS

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be better to just use it straight from Google. Then you don't need to worry about any copyright issues and it's free.

[http://www.google.com/webfonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:](http://www.google.com/webfonts#QuickUsePlace%3aquickUse/Family%3a)

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox (Gecko), [web fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face) are subject to the same domain restriction (**font files must be on the same domain as the page using them**), unless HTTP access controls are used to relax this restriction.

Note: Because there are no defined MIME types for TrueType, OpenType, and Web Open File Format (WOFF) fonts, the MIME type of the file specified is not considered.

Answer (score 0):

i had this exact same issue a couple weeks ago.

all i did was add `local('*Name of Font*)` so that the browser would look for the font

Firefox is weird. I've noticed in development local servers it will try to load the font from your install font sets before trying to actually look for the src font in the path you specify.

Thats were local will help it will tell it to look in local font sets.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use:

```
<base href="http://www.site.com/" />
```

If so, change it to:

```
<base href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>" />
```