# How to link to a .woff font file in html document

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-family

I have a problem with a font I installed on my computer that I want to apply to HTML5 / CSS3.

*How my question differs from its possible duplicate: it explicitely asks what to put in the .html file, a question that was unaddressed in the duplicate question.*

Update after problem solved:

1) The `<link href=....>` line must NOT be included in the .html file

2) The .woff font file must be in the same directory as the .css file.

This is my minimal working CSS:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Reef;
    src: local('../Fonts/Reef/reef-webfont.woff'), url('../Fonts/Reef/reef-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}

body, h1, h2{   
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Reef', monospace; 
}
```

And this is my minimal working HTML file:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
    libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>    

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesGrilcheeserie.css" type="text/css"/>     
        <link href='../Fonts/Reef/reef-webfont.woff' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title> Grilcheeserie </title>          
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>La Grilcheeserie</h1>       

    </body>
</html>
```

Whatever I do, my page appears with its backup font, monospace, not Reef.

My question is: how do I correctly reference the font source in the html? As far as I can tell from searching answers, my css is supposed to be right.

I'm using Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@font-face url pointing to local file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812111/font-face-url-pointing-to-local-file)

Comment: You could also check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837249/font-face-src-local-how-to-use-the-local-font-if-the-user-already-has-it

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: @ Jesse Kernaghan: Upmost level: /HTML-CSS-JS   Then Fonts/ and Grilcheeserie/ are on the same next level. The .html and .css are inside Grilcheeserie/. The font .eot, .woff and .otf files are inside Fonts/Reef/ where Fonts is the same folder as in the previous sentence.

Comment: @LGSon: The post you mention does not address the line to put inside the head section of the .html file.

Comment: You don't reference font file like that. "Head in Cloud" gave you an answer about that.

Answer (score 13):

`<link href='../Fonts/Reef/reef-webfont.woff' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`
 you cannot reference a  font like this.

```
@font-face{
font-family: Reef;
src: url('reef-webfont.woff'), url('reef-webfont.woff') format('woff');}
```

put your fonts in the same directory where this style file is located

Comment: Hurray! It worked! What I did: 1) put .woff file in same folder as .css file 2) removed <link href= .......> line from .html file 3) copy-pasted the src: .... line from your comment instead of the src: .... I previously had. Thank you people!

Comment: Works for otf too.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, your `local` source should just display the name of the font as it's installed on your machine. The `url` source should point to where the font file is in relation to your **CSS file location**:

`local('Reef'), url('/Path/To/My/Font/reef-webfont.woff')`