# To use local font in HTML using font face

Tags: html, css, font-face

I trying to use local font to apply styles in html, below is the code.Font is not getting applied for harlow class used element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src:local("C:\Users\Website\fonts\Harlow_Solid_Italic.ttf");
}

.harlow{
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>With CSS3, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre selected "web-safe" fonts.</div>
<p><b class="harlow">Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the @font-face rule with the WOFF format (only support for EOT format).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to open the developer console (F12), what does it say?

Comment: `local` can't be used to access files by path. That would be a security flaw. You can only give the font name. First make sure the font is installed on your computer and not just downloaded.

Comment: Try that : font-family: "myFirstFont";
Font name must be in quotation marks.
Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698319/css-font-face-what-does-src-local-mean

4castle have right

Comment: use `url` instead of local, and wrap `myFirstFont` in quotation.

Comment: @M.Tanzil Neither of those are necessary. Quotes are only needed when the font name contains a space. Look at some [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#Examples)

Comment: @Bálint The console won't always show CSS errors like that. Chrome didn't when I tested the code.

Comment: @4castle Yes, but the problem is maybe a security error

Comment: Duplicate of several answered questions. This one's probably useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812111/font-face-url-pointing-to-local-file

Comment: You can't use `c:\path\file`, you need to use `file:///path/file`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I made the following changes and I got the result

- Quotation marks for font-family
- Using of URL instead of local
- Changing of "\" to "/"

**Note:**
Use of the `local` css function throws an error in the developer console saying resource  is not loaded. See the modified code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "myFirstFont";
    src: url("C:/Users/Desktop/Website/fonts/Harlow_Solid_Italic.ttf");
}

.harlow {
    font-family: "myFirstFont";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>With CSS3, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre selected "web-safe" fonts.</div>
<p><b class="harlow">Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the @font-face rule with the WOFF format (only support for EOT format).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should change `src:url("C:/path/to/ttf");` to `src:url("file:///path/to/file")`.

Answer (score 15):

**Use font face in all the format types according to the browser compatibility**

Just add bellow code before all the styling of your css file and then you can use this font family for any selector inside within your css file.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CustomHeading';
    src: url('./fonts/SFAtarianSystem.ttf') format('embedded-opentype'), /* Internet Explorer */
         url('./fonts/SFAtarianSystem.ttf') format('woff2'),             /* Super Modern Browsers */
         url('./fonts/SFAtarianSystem.ttf') format('woff'),              /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url('./fonts/SFAtarianSystem.ttf') format('truetype'),          /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('./fonts/SFAtarianSystem.ttf') format('svg');               /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the correct path for file.
your path does not work on the host. because your host has no drive 'c:/...' or anythings like this.
so you can use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src:url("/fonts/Harlow_Solid_Italic.ttf");
}

.harlow{
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>With CSS3, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre selected "web-safe" fonts.</div>
<p><b class="harlow">Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, do not support the @font-face rule with the WOFF format (only support for EOT format).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with this code. I tried it on multiple sites and it worked pretty well.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src:url("D:\Files\Design\Fonts\SF-Pro-Text-Font-Family");
}

* {
  font-family: myFirstFont !important;
}
```