# Why my font doesn't show up with @font-face?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I know there are already topics about it, but I have not found a solution to my problem. It may be a silly question but I feel like I've checked everything: the link to my folder, the extensions, the names of the folders and files ... I can't see what is wrong in my code. thank you so much

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"NeutrifRegular";
    src: url("fonts/NeutrifRegular.otf") format("otf"),
           url("fonts/NeutrifRegular.ttf") format("ttf");
   }

body {
    background-color: #f1efee;
    font-family:"NeutrifRegular";
}
```

overview of my files :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kTYk.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB0pb.jpg

overview of my console :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg1Vx.jpg

Comment: probably a path issue, try `"../fonts/NeutrifRegular.ttf"` etc.

Comment: Have you tried the solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086083/to-use-local-font-in-html-using-font-face

Comment: Thank you all. Paulie_D my folder is at the same level as my css file (we see it on my previews).
Roy my problem is not on mobile but on PC
TRIKONINFOSYSTEMS my problem is not the same. My code seems similar to the given solution. There must be another problem that I don't see ...

Comment: Depends what browser you are trying to view it in - you don't seem to have included all font types to cover all browsers (you seem to be missing your woff versions) and if your fonts folder is on the same level as the css folder, your relative path is wrong (I cannot see your image as my firewall blocks imigur)

Comment: Pete : Thank you ! Need a woff version? I will ask for it. I do not manage the files.
Why my path is wrong I don't understand? I am in my css file and I have to go to the fonts folder to recover my typography. The fonts folder is at the same level as my css file

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the wrong format type.

https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-fonts-3-20180920/#src-desc

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:"NeutrifRegular";
    src: url("fonts/NeutrifRegular.otf") format("opentype"),
           url("fonts/NeutrifRegular.ttf") format("truetype");
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have the formats that I'm given ... I will ask for more.

Comment: You wrote `format("ttf")` and `format("otf")`, but ALL browsers don't understand this syntax. You need wrote `format("truetype")` and `format("opentype")` instead.

Comment: Now it's only the format that should not be adapted to any browser because it works on Google Chromes. Thank you !

Comment: I added the woff format and it still does not work on firefox