# Load Font from a Module in CSS

Tags: css, node-modules

I am trying to use a font that is in a node_module.

My CSS file looks something like this:

```css
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'OwnLight';
    src: url("require('font-database/fonts/Own-Light-Regulat.tff')");
  }
```

I also tried doing these:

```css
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'OwnLight';
    src: url("~font-database/fonts/Own-Light-Regulat.tff");
  }
```

```css
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'OwnLight';
    src: "~font-database/fonts/Own-Light-Regulat.tff";
  }
```

```css
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'OwnLight';
    src: require('font-database/fonts/Own-Light-Regulat.tff');
  }
```

But nothing works.

Also tried appending `format("truetype")` on the `src` - also to no avail.

Any way I can do this?
Thanks!

Comment: First, your file extension should probably be `.ttf` instead of `.tff`. Check also if the font's name is really Own-Light-**Regulat** or is it maybe Own-Light-**Regular**? Maybe another typo? Finally, try using `src: url('font-database/fonts/Own-Light-Regulat.ttf');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To use local font in HTML using font face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086083/to-use-local-font-in-html-using-font-face)