# FontFace, Firefox Problems... Using Font Squirrel

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

On my page I call the font as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/Bebas/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" /><!---BebasRegular --->
```

Then when I refer to the font I use code such as this:

```
#pagewrapper {
    font: 14px/1.4 'BebasRegular', sans-serif;
          }
```

Finally, I use the following code directly from font squirrel:

```
/* Generated by Font Squirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com) on July 18, 2012 03:57:10     PM America/New_York */
@font-face {
font-family: "BebasRegular";
src: url('BEBAS___-webfont.eot');
src: url('BEBAS___-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('BEBAS___-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('BEBAS___-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('BEBAS___-webfont.svg#BebasRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

I simply unpacked directly from font squirrel and did not change any of the other files or move anything out of the directory.

So, the font works perfectly on chrome, ie and safari.  However, in Firefox is does not work.  I know this is not a very interesting question--but I am clueless.  What is going wrong? Can anyone spot the issue?

I feel like its such a simple set up that there shouldn't be room for any issues... :)

Comment: See [css @font-face not working with firefox, but working with chrome and IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried adding the suggested text to the hta and I tried to do the workaround using 64 encode.  Still the same result.

Comment: Can you post this (code & font data) to a URL we can access? Could possibly be a problem with the font data itself; I have seen a few cases like that. I can take a crack at examining and testing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check the font family name. How you call the font is different in the two instances

```
font-family: "BebasRegular";
```

and

```
font: 14px/1.4 'BebasNeueRegular', sans-serif;
```

Try **BebasRegular** as defined in @font-face:

```
#pagewrapper {
font: 14px/1.4 'BebasRegular', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, but that was just sloppy question writing on my part. I grabbed from the wrong font call on of the times.  I use both bebas and bebasneueregular.  Thanks though.  Ill change that in the question