# CSS font-face not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I have this font face code below and it works fine in google chrome, but it doesnt work at all in firefox? why?

```
    <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Reg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Reg.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Reg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Reg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Reg-webfont.svg#LatoRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoBold';
    src: url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Bol-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Bol.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Bol-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Bol-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Bol-webfont.svg#LatoBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

nav ul li{
    font-family: 'LatoBold', sans-serif !important;
}
    </style>

 <nav id="mainNav">
            <ul class="grid_0">
                            <li>
                        <a href="http://www.website.com">Home</a>
                        </li></ul>
```

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie

Comment: The font files are not found, e.g. http://www.website.com/fonts/ca/Lato-Bol-webfont.woff yields an HTML response. Possibly you have magic that serves other code to other browsers. ☺

Answer (score 1):

It seems your font link is broken. if I may suggest you, just use [google web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts). There are many fonts that can be used for your website, easy to use and free. Lato's Font also there.

See my the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/Nx5VR/

the css rules below

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'LatoBold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/wkfQbvfT_02e2IWO3yYueQ.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/9k-RPmcnxYEPm8CNFsH2gg.woff) format('woff');
}
```

is the result of the extraction from google font link :

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Hope its help :)