# HTML And CSS Custom Font is not coming on my page

Tags: html, css, fonts

This is my html code---->

```
        <div data-role="page" id="page1" >

            <div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">
                 <h1>header</h1>        
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                 <p id="myfont">content</p>
            </div>

             <div data-role="footer" >
                 <h1>footer</h1>
              </div>
      </div>
 </body>
```

This is my CSS code------->

```
   @font-face{
    font-family:'Byron Medium';
    src:url('byronmedium.ttf');
       // font-size:'60px';
    }
  div #myfont{
    font-family:'Byron Medium';
    font-size:'60px';   
     }
```

My Custom font-family and font-size is coming on page please help me

Comment: What browser? Can you access `byronmedium.tff` from the browser? What is the response code for `byronmedium.tff` in `Network` tab of Chrome DevTools/Firebug/...? What's its mime type? Is the style shown when you inspect that element in DevTools/Firebug/...?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785088/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox/14785149#14785149

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd say your font name is wrong.

try

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Byron Medium';
    src:url('byronmedium.ttf');
    // font-size:'60px';
}
```

true-type fonts are generally .ttf, no ?

Answer (score 1):

please try this may i sure your solution done.

please add `eot, woff, svg, formate` and add `@font-face` kit on your css style.

```
    @font-face{
        font-family:'Byron Medium';
        src:url('byronmedium.tff');
           // font-size:'60px';
        src: url('byronmedium-webfont.eot');
         src: url('byronmedium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                         url('byronmedium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                         url('byronmedium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
                         url('byronmedium-webfont.svg#byronmedium') format('svg');
                    font-weight: normal;
                    font-style: normal;
    }

      .myfont{
        font-family:'Byron Medium';
        font-size:'60px';   

     }
```

HTML

```
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" >

        <div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">
             <h1>header</h1>        
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
             <p class="myfont">content</p>
        </div>

         <div data-role="footer" >
             <h1>footer</h1>
          </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector to apply the font is `div #myfont`, but you're selecting on an id, so the `div` is redundant.

Try changing this:

```
div #myfont{
 font-family:'Byron Medium';
 font-size:'60px';   
}
```

to this:

```
#myfont{
 font-family:'Byron Medium';
 font-size:'60px';   
}
```

or better still, use a class (`.myFont`), and apply that to any element that you want to use the font for.

Comment: he's using `div #myfont {}` rather than `div#myfont {}` , to select the descendant. This seems correct to me

Comment: `div #myfont` is `#myfont` as a child of `div`. why do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: @DomDay Whoops -  missed that. Nevertheless, the `div` selector is redundant, since he's selecting on an id.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the div element from your css definition,

```
@font-face{
font-family:'Byron Medium';
src:url('byronmedium.tff');
   // font-size:'60px';
}

#myfont
{
font-family:'Byron Medium';
font-size:'60px';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the element with the `myfont` `id` is a paragraph that is not a child of a division, your current selector matches nothing in your sample markup. Change it to

`#myfont { /*...*/ }`

Also, for better browser support, you'll want to look into adding more file formats than `.ttf`, unless you know for a fact that you're only dealing with browsers that can handle TrueType fonts.

Answer (score -1):

use can apply @font to `<p>` tag which is inside div
you can use `div p{font-family:myFirstFont;}` or 
apply class to `<p class="yourclassname">` or 
remove the `div` from your css