# Font not displaying properly in firefox

Tags: html, css

Embedded Opensans font in my site. It's display fine in chrome, but not display properly in firefox. In firefox font display like blurred.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot');
    src: local('OpenSans-Regular'), url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.otf') format('open-truetype'),
        url('../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.svg#opensans') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Not only opensans font , i tried two more fonts it's also have same problem. But other site displayed fine. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css @font-face not working with firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785088/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox)

Comment: Show a *complete* example, with HTML and CSS code, and identify the source of the font and the tool used to generate the font files. You might want to *first* check whether the problem also appears when using Open Sans as hosted by Google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSans;
    src: url(../fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSansLight;
    src: url(../fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSansBold;
    src: url(../fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf);
}
```

All works fine with that. You could look in the elements console if all resources are loaded correctly.

Comment: resources are loaded correctly, but it's not work fine

Comment: With my method? Can you show me your css where you add a font-family to an element?