# @fontface issues with firefox and yahoo hosting

Tags: firefox, font-face

I have a problem that was answered in this thread here: [CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

but my client is hosted on yahoo hosting, which doesn't allow .htaccess files. Is there any alternative other than switching hosts? (which my client will not want to do)

Here is a link to the site: http://iwilldestroyyou.com/main/

Comment: What are you hosting? Static HTML, some kind of CMS, or what?

Comment: I'm hosting wordpress

Comment: As far as I can tell fonts are working fine on your website with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

What works best for me is placing the font file's in the same directory as the .css file, no hassle with anny .htaccess or other server config file's.

So i have one external fonts.css file containing all the css font line's within the font directory. Then i can include this .css file on the page i would like to use this font. Make sure you don't make additional directory's so you can call the font without anny directory.

*more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face*