# @font-face works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

Chrome and Safari are showing the (local) be fonts correctly, but Firefox isn't.
The code I got from Fontsquirl added ' marks in the code, which I got rid of, but it's still not working:

### Original code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'frutigerboldcn';
src: url('frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.eot');
src: url('frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.svg#frutigerboldcn') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

### I changed it into:

```
@font-face {
font-family: frutigerboldcn;
src: url(frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.eot);
src: url(frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype),
     url(frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.woff) format(woff),
     url(frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.ttf) format(truetype),
     url(frutiger_67_bold_condensed-webfont.svg#frutigerboldcn) format(svg);
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

Fonts are loaded in the same folder as the stylesheet.

### This is part of the stylesheet regarding the navigation:

```
#navigation .sf-menu a {
display: inline;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #008abf; 
border-radius: 2px;
padding: 0 5px;
height: 26px;
line-height: 26px;
font-weight: normal;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: frutigerboldcn;
```

How do I fix this? Thanx in advance

Comment: Is the stylesheet in the document root? or is it in a subdirectory, like /css/? I'd suggest putting the path relative to the document root in the url statements.

Comment: Have a look at the syntax-highlighting above - did you recognize something? Do you really think Fontsquirrel adds `'` marks for all the thousands of users, which everyone then has to remove ...!? Are all your files (html, css and the font files) really in the same directory? And is every font file present and delivered to the browser?

Comment: I think all you need is in this link:  
**[css @font-face not working with firefox, but working with chrome and IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie?rq=1)**

Comment: @Saber Haj Rabiee: The answer you linked to has something to do with trying to load the font files from **local** resource. Same problem may occur when using absolute URIs. Neither is the case here.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but if the font is really bold, couldn't Firefox reject it because it wants to show its text non-bold? Test it with a bold font weight.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your .htaccess and all will be fine, at least on modern FF versions.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Go here for the full discussion on Stack Overflow:
[CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArialRounded';
    src: url('ArialRounded.eot');
    src: local('ArialRounded'), url('fonts/ArialRounded.eot'); /* for firefox */
    }

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArialRounded';
    src: url('ArialRounded.woff') format('woff'),
    src: local('ArialRounded'), url('fonts/ArialRounded.woff'); /* for firefox */
    url('ArialRounded.svg#ArialRounded') format('svg');
    src: local('ArialRounded'), url('fonts/ArialRounded.svg'); /* for firefox */
    }
```

Comment: This works for me, but YMMV. The reason is that firefox is paranoid and thinks that if you're not giving http:// with the server name in the url of the font, that you're doing cross-site scripting