# Font's and font face not working on godaddy server

Tags: php, fonts, font-face

I am using near about 300 font all of 300 working good on local host but when i upload on server they not work.I am using .ttf and .otf file extinctions.
Bellow is my sample code.

```
/*8Bit font */
  @font-face { font-family: 8_bit_1_6 Regular; src: url('fonts/8bit16.TTF'); }
  @font-face { font-family: Pixelic War; src: url('fonts/Pixelic War.TTF'); }
  @font-face { font-family: PKMN Pinball; src: url('fonts/PKMN-Pinball.TTF'); }
  @font-face { font-family: TerrabloX; src: url('fonts/TerrabloX.TTF'); }
```

[See my live link](http://cutting-edge.bluecoresys.com/wordpress_theme/)

Comment: Is there any pattern to which aren't working? Like all the .otf don't work, or all the ones with spaces in the name? Did they all upload correctly? Have you tried re-uploading them?

Comment: Could be a path issue, as in firebug the ajax requests to the fonts are 404

Comment: some .otf font working but .ttf not working have you seen my link @FDL

Comment: There is no error 404 and any @LawrenceCherone

Comment: @SanjayNakate Are you sure about that lol http://i.imgur.com/YNFeN4C.jpg

Comment: Hai lawrence i got the solution there is issue with file extensions.my  old file extension was .TTF ,.OTF now i am using .ttf , .otf and and correcting some file names its working now better ... @LawrenceCherone

Comment: This solution might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9570757/327862

Comment: i have done it before 7 month ago ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution there is issue with file extensions.my old file extension was .TTF ,.OTF now i am using .ttf , .otf .some time it not work for specific file then use .TTF ,.OTF  and remove space, - from  file names  its working now better .