# @font-face still not working in FireFox. Issue with type of font?

Tags: .htaccess, css, firefox, fonts

I am aware that this question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie) but I have tried the solutions mentioned to no affect.

My CSS declration looks like:

```
@font-face { 
      font-family: gillsans; 
      src: url('gillsans.TTF'); 
    }
```

This works in Chrome but not FireFox.

Weirdly enough, I have another site that uses the exact same declaration but with a different font and it works fine:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: bebas;
    src: url('bebas.TTF');
}
```

Could this have something to do with the actual font file?

I have also tried modifying my .htaccess file as suggested:

```
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Again no results in FireFox.

I have tried changing `.TTF` to `.tff` and providing absolute paths to the file, but still nothing.

Can anyone suggest something I can try?

The only possible thing could be is that this site is in development and is thus using a temporary URL, but I dont understand how that could effect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I downloaded another version of Gill Sans (still ttf) and replaced the one I have it that fixed it. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Try other font types like eot,woff & svg. To convert you can use http://www.onlinefontconverter.com/

and then try this code in your style or css file:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family:'bebas';
    src:url('bebas.eot');/*IE9 or later*/
    src:local('bebas'),/*check for font installation*/
        local('b ebas'),/*check for font installation in some browsers like Safari*/
        url('bebas.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),/*hack for IE8 or earlier*/
        url('bebas.woff') format('woff'),/*new browsers*/
        url('bebas.ttf') format('truetype'),/*all browsers excpet IE*/
        url('bebas.svg#bebas') format('svg');/*old iOs*/
}
.bebas-ft{
    font-family:bebas, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

And also do not modify your .htaccess file for such simple matter!