# Custom font not loaded properly in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I'm trying to use custom font for my client live website. The font is working properly in **Chrome**, **Safari**, **Opera** as well as in **IE** but not working in **Firefox**.I follow the **[Manuel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie/3704578#3704578)** solution that works fine but when I see the firefox network log it show that loaded font size is only **0KB**. If I directly open the font link it start downloading font with it's original size.

Comment: local-server or live-url????

Comment: have you tried giving absolute path??

Comment: @NoobEditor Yes I tried that but Nah!

Comment: please give the live url if it is not client-violation!!

Comment: @NoobEditor That's the main issue I can't share the URL. Sorry buddy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45269/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-muhammad-bilal)