# Using font-face on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, font-face

After reading many tutorials, many websites, I still haven't find a fix...
I'm using custom font for my website... Last thing I tried was the [Paul Irish's method](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) but it still doesn't work on Firefox 26. Here's what I have in mys css file :

```
@font-face 
{ 
    font-family: 'Logo';
    src: url('mohave-semibold_italics-webfont.eot');
    src: url('mohave-semibold_italics-webfont.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
         url('mohave-semibold_italics-webfont.woff') format("woff"),
         url('mohave-semibold_italics-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"),
         url('mohave-semibold_italics-webfont.svg#mohavesemibold_italic') format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I've tried many things and currently I have the fonts in the same directory that my css file. If anyone have the solution, please help me :)

Thanks

NB : The website isn't on a server, it's all local on my filesystem (for now)

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

Comment: Not enough data. Where does the font come from, how did you generate the font files, what does the Network pane in browser console say, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pinal said, it's indeed a duplicate of [CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie) 
Didn't found this one. thanks to him !