# Apache2 @font-face

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, font-face, woff

I'm having a problem with my fonts on server, in Chrome everything look great, but in Mozilla and IE font is not loaded.

I understand that problem is in Apache configuration. But I tried all solutions with adding mime types to .htaccess, to mime.type and apache2.conf; added mod_headers settings to .htaccess - nothing helped.

What could be the problem?

My CSS code is:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNovaCond-Reg';
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaCond-Reg.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaCond-Reg.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNovaCond-Reg.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNovaCond-Reg.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

URL: http://demo2.even.lv/

Thanks.

Comment: You're having a CORS issue perhaps.

Comment: Why do you think it is an Apache configuration issue?

Comment: @dachi tried this, no results

Comment: I hope this thread can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie

Comment: @IMSoP, I had same issue with FontAwesome, but I was lazy and fixed that by using BootstrapCDN url. In this case I really need to fix this.

Comment: @httpd, it doesn't solves my issue.