# CSS embedded font not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'exoregular';
    src: url('exo-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('exo-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('exo-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('exo-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('exo-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('exo-regular-webfont.svg#exoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I've added a font to my website, however it doesn't not show up in firefox, does anyone know why this is the case?

My CSS is above and my fonts are inside my CSS styles folder.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Using something like [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Browser Specific css using this code for Firefox,  http://browserhacks.com/ is good source for browser specific CSS hacks or you can just do a Google search for Browser Specific CSS.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
          @font-face {
    font-family: 'exoregular';
    src: url('exo-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('exo-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('exo-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('exo-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('exo-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('exo-regular-webfont.svg#exoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunetly that has done nothing, do you have any other idea's?

Comment: @ScottShannon Sorry to hear that, perhaps this answer may help you more [link]http://stackoverflow.com/a/3704578/4504776[link]