# Font face compatability problems in the browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts

- I am trying apply font(xxx.woff) for my page. Below is the code. By using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)  , i have applied font css Css is below.

---

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'xxx';
    src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAJGG+N4ZgOyNL7RJAKI1J6TtUwuql7QX9RAaoHhg1UdowyYC8YFlAeM0qApRlFoBQwamH0EEr6gl1HWcsYDlCfMhqA4/8gyeXXOkjda0HnKj6AbbCzNWyB7ZlhE2xNDL3PbTd7CZN0seA9DX2wmxn2QH9jGIC92LAPBqM/U/L0G+ADZwQAAAAAAVfa6j8AAA==) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
* {
        font-family: PB-Regular;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: # !important;
    }
```

- Above code is working in Version 40.0.2214.111 Ubuntu 14.04,Firefox 35.0.1 Ubuntu 14.04. Except those 2 versions,its not work in any other browsers.
- Please suggest me what should be done to work in all versions of chrome, firefox and IE9

Comment: Is that your real CSS code? The `font-family` values don't match.

Comment: font family is PB-Regular

Comment: The `font-family` you define in your `@font-face` rule is what you need to call the font in the rest of your CSS code... if you name it 'xxx' in the `@font-face` definition then you need to use `font-family: 'xxx'` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (someone please correct me if I'm wrong) that .woff is only compatible with select browsers.

Add the font in .ttf to support other browsers.

Comment: tried .ttf  also its not working,link which i have tried is https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 0):

When you define an `@font-face` rule, the name you give the `font-family` value you use is the value you must use in the rest of the document:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'xxx';
  src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAJGG+N4ZgOyNL7RJAKI1J6TtUwuql7QX9RAaoHhg1UdowyYC8YFlAeM0qApRlFoBQwamH0EEr6gl1HWcsYDlCfMhqA4/8gyeXXOkjda0HnKj6AbbCzNWyB7ZlhE2xNDL3PbTd7CZN0seA9DX2wmxn2QH9jGIC92LAPBqM/U/L0G+ADZwQAAAAAAVfa6j8AAA==) format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
* {
  font-family: 'xxx'; /* You must use the value from the @font-face rule */           
  font-size: 16px;
  color: # !important;
}
```