# CSS @font-face Base64 encoded font, only works in IE, not in chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, font-face

The following code font only works fine in IE , Not in Chrome or Firefox. Any idea ?

```
 @font-face {
          font-family: 'Free 3 of 9';
          src: url(data:font/ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,"Encoded String for font") format('truetype');
          font-weight: normal;
          font-style: normal;
          }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS @font-face not working with Firefox, but working with Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie)

Comment: No this is different, Here I want to use base64 encoded value for font, not an url for the font file