# Font is loading but not showing on Firefox

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I have this code to provide a new font-face
(I'm using symfony)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "keplericon";
    src: url("{{ asset('fonts/keplericon/keplericon.eot')|raw }}") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("{{ asset('fonts/keplericon/keplericon.woff2')|raw }}") format("woff2"),
        url("{{ asset('fonts/keplericon/keplericon.woff')|raw }}") format("woff"),
        url("{{ asset('fonts/keplericon/keplericon.svg')|raw }}") format("svg");
}
```

And in the css, I have

```
.icon { font-family: keplericon }
```

In Chrome, this works like a charm. But it's not working in Firefox. I have verified that the font is downloaded by going to `Network` -> filter by `Font` and see my file downloaded (which is the woff2 file)

But nothing show up. Checking the HTML inspection, this shows up

[image: Weird box]

Any help would be appreciated :D. Thanks!

Comment: @ShirishMaharjan go to the same question?

Comment: goto:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie?rq=1

Comment: @ShirishMaharjan as I have mentioned in my post, I have confirmed that ff actually downloaded my font. So none of the answers in that post can help me out.