# @font-face not working for Chrome and Firefox on iOS only

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

Page URL: http://seasia.kinsta.cloud/static/home-free-subscriber.html

I have used custom fonts on this page using @font-face. It's working fine on all desktop browsers, and also on Android browsers. **Fonts are not loading only on iOS (iPhone and iPad) on Firefox and Chrome browsers.** Working fine on Safari on iOS.

---

I have tried adding .htaccess file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856502/css-font-face-not-working-with-firefox-but-working-with-chrome-and-ie) on another discussion.

Also tried font smoothing properties as suggested here: https://github.com/grillitype/web-fonts-guide#font-smoothing

But it didn't help.

---

Following is the code I have used in CSS for @font-face

```
@font-face {
font-family: "GT America Black";
src: url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Black.eot");
src: local("GT America Black"), 
     local("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Black"), 
     url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Black.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
     url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Black.woff2") format("woff2"), 
     url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Black.woff") format("woff"), 
     url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Black.ttf") format("truetype");
font-weight: 900;
font-style: normal;
font-stretch: normal; }

@font-face {
font-family: "GT America Light";
src: url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Light.eot");
src: local("GT America Light"), 
     local("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Light"), 
     url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Light.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
     url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Light.woff2") format("woff2"), 
     url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Light.woff") format("woff"), 
     url("../fonts/gt-america/GT-America-Standard-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
font-stretch: normal; }
```

Comment: your woff2 archive is broken or not loaded and you are calling it in the css. Maybe that may be the problem...

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez Can you please elaborate this with some more details?